# Add fixed size Array into List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, set

How to add String[] into Set avoiding exception.
I put array's size to 100, it doesn't need to be fixed size array but 
I need to have access to array's members like x[] so i can insert array values.

```
Set<String[]> s = new TreeSet<String[]>();
String[] x = new String[100];
int i=0;
x[i++] = ...
x[i++] = ...
s.add(x);



Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
```

Comment: What do you understand by this exception? `String[]` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Comparable`

Comment: use HashSet or LinkedHashSet. TreeSet maintains sort order and elements being added must be mutually comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays don't have a "natural order", that's why you got this exception.

One way is to provide a custom comparator when constructing your `TreeSet`.

```
Set<String[]> s = new TreeSet<String[]>(new Comparator<String[]>() {    
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
             //your logic here
        }
    });
```

But I don't think you should use a `TreeSet` for that sort of things because that will be hard to tell how to define an order for comparing your arrays.

IMO your best option is to create a wrapper class, overriding hashcode and equals and put those in an `HashSet`.

```
class WrapperStringArray {
    private String[] arr;

    //constructors, getters, setter and additional methods

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(arr);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        WrapperStringArray other = (WrapperStringArray) obj;
        return Arrays.equals(arr, other.arr);
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks man, your suggestion about order was crucial, i just put HashSet instead of TreeSet cause I need to have unique arrays in set.

Comment: @fpopic Yes, but you need to use a wrapper class, as Arrays don't override hashcode and equals method.